# AppEngine megacycles to cost

Tags: google-app-engine

I have profiled my code on AppEngine and some of the code says it takes 158 megacycles to run...ok, and CPU usage on AppEngine in $0.10 an hour.

What, if any is the sum to work out how much that 158 megacycles cost? I should imagine, it's quite small, something like: $0.00001 ? perhaps? - but whats the sum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Google's FAQ](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/billing.html#rounding):

> 1 megacycle = 1/1200 CPU second

Comment: so at that rate:

1 megacycle = 1/1200 CPU second, 3600seconds per hour

4320000 megacycles per hour = $0.10

Answer (score 2):

GAE provides you with a handy way to project the cost of a request:

> If you access your site while signed in using an administrator account, App Engine includes per-request statistics in the response headers. The header X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars represents an estimate of what 1,000 requests similar to this request would cost in US dollars. The header X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage represents the resources used by the request, including server-side time, app server CPU time, and API CPU time, each as a number of milliseconds.

See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Responses