# What is the easiest way to find the most expensive queries in my App Engine app?

Tags: performance, google-app-engine

I'm not familiar with any analytics software other than Google Analytics. I'd rather not get into BigQuery or write much code for this really.

I am looking for a spreadsheet showing how much each URL cost me in the past 7 days.

Comment: use appstats and profile your application.

Answer (score 3):

Appstats!

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

> To keep your application fast, you need to know:
>
> Is your application making unnecessay RPC calls? Should it be caching
>   data instead of making repeated RPC calls to get the same data? Will
>   your application perform better if multiple requests are executed in
>   parallel rather than serially? The Appstats library helps you answer
>   these questions and verify that your application is using RPC calls in
>   the most efficient way by allowing you to profile your RPC calls.
>   Appstats allows you to trace all RPC calls for a given request and
>   **reports on the time and cost of each call.**

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for a way to find the operations that cost me the most money. This means multiplying the CPU time x cost x pageviews. Appstats gets me only one of those 3 factors.

Comment: Actually appstats does show you the combination those 3 factors, have you tried it?

Comment: also see one of the answers here, a "cost" is included in the headers if desired. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213576/appengine-megacycles-to-cost